# How does unique_ptr know to call delete[] on an array?

Tags: c++

Can anyone provide any insight into how `unique_ptr` chooses between using `delete` and `delete[]` in the destructor? I assume there's some interesting type traits tricks there that would be useful to understand.

Comment: If you have a `unique_ptr<T[]>`, a template specialization kicks in

Comment: there is specialization for `T[]`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) you'll see there's a template specialization that has a different `Deleter` for arrays

```
template<
    class T,
    class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>
> class unique_ptr;

template <
    class T,
    class Deleter
> class unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>;
```

As they note

> There are two versions of std::unique_ptr:
>
> 1) Manages a single object (e.g. allocated with `new`)
>   2) Manages a dynamically-allocated array of objects (e.g. allocated with `new[]`)

Comment: It is the specialization of [`std::default_delete<T[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) which is important here.